# How to deal with MyBatis in WebFlux stack

Tags: java, spring-webflux, mybatis

I have a huge enterprise java application wtitten with "ye olde good" stack of technologies: Spring Web MVC, PostgreSQL, MyBatis. Let's *assume* there is a real need to migrate the application to reactive stack. This means old Postrges JDBC driver and MyBatis will be not applicable anymore since they have a blocking nature. And this in turn means the whole DB layer (MyBatis mappers) have to be refactored with one of r2dbc implementations. And this is a really big deal!

So the question is: is there any hack to use existing mappers along with reactive Fluxes and Monos? Maybe some callback-like solution or something?

UPD
`Mono` has a `fromFuture` method. The following code is valid and it works just as expected. But is it really reactive by it spirit?

```
public Mono<User> getUserById(Long id) {
   return Mono.fromFuture(
      CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> userMapper.getUser(id)));
}
```

Comment: It's important the database can produce back pressure to your application. With reactive programming you could be ignoring that back pressure.

Comment: Good question, btw. I'll be curious to see more opinions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long answer I'm afraid - this is a *big* topic to unpack generally. But the tl;dr is you *can*, but you probably shouldn't.

### You certainly can...

> So the question is: is there any hack to use existing mappers along with reactive Fluxes and Monos? Maybe some callback-like solution or something?

Many reactive frameworks, reactor included, have mechanisms designed to do just this. You keep your traditional blocking libraries in the reactive chain, but you make sure they're executed in a traditional threadpool so they don't tie up the event loop threads (these must *never* block, that's critical.) In Webflux / reactor, you'd use [`Schedulers.boundedElastic()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#boundedElastic--) which is meant for just this purpose - it'll maintain an elastic pool of workers which will scale up and down as necessary, processing items as and when they appear.

As an aside, this is pretty much what your example there is doing - recall that [`supplyAsync()` uses the common ForkJoin pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-), so all it's doing is delegating your task to a threadpool-backed executor. Unlike reactors `boundedElastic()` however, the fork join pool won't scale up and down based on your requirements, so it's not as suited for the task.

### ...but you shouldn't.

**Possible** certainly doesn't mean you should. By executing your tasks in this way, you're losing *all* the benefits of the reactive framework for this particular piece of code - most crucially, you retain the context switching you're trying to avoid (the key driver of using a reactive stack in the first place.)

If you're palming your entire DB layer off onto a blocking threadpool, then there's going to be little to no gain in using a reactive framework to begin with.

### Would you ever?

That doesn't mean to say you should *never* use it however. For big, application critical components such as your DB layer it's a complete no-no in my book. But the above approach can work well if you have a kind of auxiliary service to your application that's not often used and performance isn't critical - say you had an old blocking DB connection that was only ever used for a piece of seldom-used error reporting functionality for instance, then using an elastic scheduler would (IMHO) be perfectly acceptable.

### So what should you do?

You'll need to move to R2DBC - that much is pretty clear to me. But you can actually still do that within the norm / safety of a *blocking* envrionment, at least initially.

When migrating older apps (assuming you've done the due diligence and it's worth doing) my preference is actually to take a "bottom-up" approach, migrating all your components to the reactive equivalent, but then calling `block()` at the point where you interface your reactive library (R2DBC in this case) to your older, blocking code. This gives you a few advantages:

- You can then run thorough tests with the new library in place, but all in your old, blocking environment - nothing else needs to change;
- It allows you to easily revert if there's an issue without changing heaps of other code;
- You can follow an incremental approach, migrating all your blocking libraries in this way one-by-one until you have a full suite of reactive libraries "ready-to-go", tried and tested;
- When you come to making the "final plunge" to switch to a fully reactive stack, you're not changing much at all - you're just switching the environment and removing some blocking calls. All the individual parts are then tried and tested.

The above isn't to say the task will be quick or easy of course - quite the opposite, especially if you're using some relatively young libraries which might have issues. But it does give you a sane approach to migrating where you can test the system bit by bit, and hopefully gain confidence at each step that things are happening exactly as they should.